# How I restrict Future Date in Calender in Android

Tags: android, calendar, android-calendar

This is My calender Picker Code.

I want to fix Max Calender with Comapre Server Date not System Date

ShowDatePicker I call from Image button click and Date Calendar is open

```
private void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
        dateFragment = new DatePickerFragment1();
        dateFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");

    }

public static class DatePickerFragment1 extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    private Context context;
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        context=getActivity();

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it

        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

        pYear = year;
        pMonth = month;
        pDay = dayOfMonth;
        Creation_Date_Display();
    }

    private void Creation_Date_Display() {
        StringBuffer DATE = (new StringBuffer().append(pYear).append("-")
                .append(pMonth + 1).append("-")
                .append(pDay).append(" "));
        // CreationDate.setText(DATE);

        // Use to make an Correct Format Of a Date
        String input = String.valueOf(DATE);
        SimpleDateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date date = null;
        try {
            date = df1.parse(input);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace(e);
        }
        String formattedDateOrder = df1.format(date);
        CreationDate.setText(formattedDateOrder);
        Creation_Date = formattedDateOrder;

    }
}
```

I am new in Android

Please Help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

below code prevent the future dates.using setMaxDate method,and takes system date.

```
     @Override
     public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        DatePickerDialog mDatePicker=new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        context=getActivity();
        mDatePicker.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it

        return mDatePicker;
    }
```

sample code for Toast:

```
if(day>c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH){
Toast.makeText(mContext, "select valid day", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return false;
}
```

Comment: bro but what is mDatePicker?

Comment: I have Implement DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener

Comment: it is an object of  DatePickerDialog.

Comment: you should change your return statment to return mDatePicker

Comment: i have update my answer check it,it will surely solve your problem

Comment: it is closely done..Future date is hide but it is select easily when i click on future date

Comment: but where i have to write this Condition and how we Compare

Answer (score 1):

try this you can use `setMaxDate()` method which is used to Sets the maximal date supported by this DatePicker in milliseconds since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 in getDefault() time zone.
[setMaxDate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html)

```
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        DatePickerDialog mDatePicker = new DatePickerDialog(SearchResultClass.this,
            R.style.MyDialogTheme,
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker datepicker, int selectedyear, int selectedmonth, int selectedday) {

                }

            }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);

           mDatePicker.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
 mDatePicker.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
```

Comment: @RishabhSaxena pDateSetListener is your date picker listner

Answer (score 1):

you have to set property like below to restrict minimum and maximum date.

```
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(mContext, R.style.DatePicker, date, myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        // to set Max Date
            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
        // to set Min Date
            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
        datePickerDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Date selectedDate = Date.valueOf(pYear+"-"+(pMonth+1)+"-"+pDay);
            if(selectedDate.getTime()>System.currentTimeMillis()){
                Toast.makeText(context, "Can not Select Future Date", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                selectedDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
               /* pYear = selectedDate.getYear()+1900;
                pMonth = selectedDate.getMonth();
                pDay = selectedDate.getDay();*/

                pYear = yearCheck;
                pMonth = monthCheck;
                pDay = dayCheck;
            }
```